# Layout does not match preview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have designed an action sheet that appears when a user press a button. It is a separate xml file that I am including in another layout file. In the layout preview, it looks exactly as I want it. However, when it runs on my phone, the layout is messed up.

Here is how it should look:

[image: Should Look]

And here is how it does look:
[image: Does Look]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Here is the layout code for the action sheet. The section that isn't displaying right is in the last linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sheet_header" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left_justified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_justified"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/alignment_left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/alignment_center" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_justified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_justified"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/alignment_right" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_justified"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sheet_done_btn"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sheet_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/font_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Font"
                android:textColor="#806014"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/size_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Size"
                android:textColor="#806014"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/color_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Color"
                android:textColor="#806014"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is how it is included:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_frame">  

    <include layout="@layout/edit_text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Edit: In addition to a fix for this specific problem does anyone know why the preview doesnt match the way it actually shows up on the phone?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why do you have the LinearLayouts at the bottom nested?

Comment: Its an unfinished layout. I still have to add some elements within that linear layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sheet_header" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left_justified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_justified"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/alignment_left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/alignment_center" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/right_justified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_justified"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/alignment_right" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_justified"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/center_justified"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sheet_done_btn"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/sheet_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/font_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Font"
                android:textColor="#806014"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/size_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Size"
                android:textColor="#806014"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/color_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Color"
                android:textColor="#806014"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the font, size, color TextViews into a Table Layout.